# How to know specification of battery

Tags: battery

As my computer is showing the 'CMOS check sum error', if I have to replace the battery , how do I know the battery specification? I have a Intel motherboard and core 2 duo processor.

Comment: If you look at the battery, it should say.

Answer (score 3):

The battery on desktops are a standard [CR2032](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CR2032_battery).

[image]

laptop cmos batteries can be too, but they're packaged in some odd format with a connector

[image]

Theres's also some other battery types so checking the service manual if its a laptop, or seeing what the manufacturer sells is a good idea.